# read file text pandas skiping some space

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming a following dataframe. I wanted to read this csv file separating the fields with a space.

```
Name Age City
jack 34   Sydeny
Riti 31  Delhi
Aadi 16 New York
Suse 32   Lucknow
Mark  33 Las vegas
Suri  35 Patna
```

I try this bus it doesn't work because i have space in New York, Las Vegas:

```
df = pd.read_csv ( 'users_5.csv' , sep= '\s+' , engine= 'python' )
```

Output expected:

```
Contents of Dataframe : 
   Name  Age       City
0  jack   34     Sydeny
1  Riti   31      Delhi
2  Aadi   16   New York
3  Suse   32    Lucknow
4  Mark   33  Las vegas
5  Suri   35      Patna
```

Comment: Your original file must escape the separator character when it's inside a field value. In this case, New York should be written as "New York".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I'm afraid you will either have to regenerate a proper csv with either quoting all text fields and keeping the space as a separator or changing the separator char.

e.g.

```
"Name" "Age" "City"
"jack" 34   "Sydeny"
"Riti" 31  "Delhi"
"Aadi" 16 "New York"
"Suse" 32   "Lucknow"
"Mark"  33 "Las vegas"
"Suri"  35 "Patna"
```

Last option if you can't rebuild the csv, is to process each line individually to build your dataframe (like if you know for sure that the first column is a single word, the second a number then you can take everything else for the last column).

I would do something like this

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'name': [],
  'age': [],
  'city': []
}


with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)  # skip the header
    for line in f:
        name, age, *city = re.split('\s+', line.strip())
        data['name'].append(name)
        data['age'].append(age)
        data['city'].append(' '.join(city))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: I take the second option. Thks it work :)